# How to get variable from php file to actionscript?

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I will write the text that getting from php file in adobe flash . how can I?

Comment: There are many different techniques for this, depending on your use case. Will the Flash app be embedded in a webpage?

Answer (score 1):

let your php-script do the output in form of a xml, which should be easy to load and processed with actionscript.